# fprintf returning null after fork() in c

Tags: c, file, process, fork

I am trying to open a file with fopen, fork the current process and make the child process write something on the file; when the child process exits, the parents process should read the file's content, but it reads "null", even if the file has been correctly written. No errors are reported.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE * sharedFile;
    char *fileContent;
    if((sharedFile = fopen("testFile.txt","w+")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error while opening the file: %s",strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        //Child
        fprintf(sharedFile,"%s",argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        //Parent
        wait(NULL);
        if(fscanf(sharedFile,"%s",fileContent) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr,"Error while reading file: %s",strerror(errno));
            return 0;
        }
        fprintf(stdout,"File content: %s",fileContent); //Outputs "File content: (null)"
        fclose(sharedFile);
    }
}
```

Oddly, if I open again the file in the parent's code after the fork, the output is correct.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Anything working while `fileContent` is an uninitialized pointer is an accident.  That's the beauty of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fileContent` has not been allocated any space. Perhaps do this

```
char fileContent[101];

...

if (fscanf(sharedFile,"%100s",fileContent) != 1) // Prevent buffer overflows. Should return one when successful.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried what you suggested, but now it prints "File content: success"

Comment: @Stubborn: And what else should it print?  That ('`success`') is presumably the first word in the file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it should print the content of the file, which is set by the child process. I have tried opening again the file with fopen in the parent's code after the fork, and the output is the desired one

Comment: @Stubborn: No.  There's no way that's what is going to happen.  The processes share the same open file description (different from an open file descriptor).  When the child writes, it moves the current position of the parent too.  Those files are much more closely related than you realize.  Your parent process would have to seek to the start of the file (`fseek(sharedFile, 0, SEEK_SET)`) before reading.  And if there was more interaction, the processes would have to coordinate more carefully. You have the simplest interaction — one writes once, the other reads once.

Comment: @Stubborn: You can read about the underlying issues in the POSIX specs for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, I was missing the fact that the current position is edited too